# Input values into link GetElementByID

Tags: javascript

Can anyone show me how to do the following:

```
onclick="window.location.href='http://www.google.com/document.getElementById("id")'
```

Obviously this is not how you do it but I'm looking for the correct way to place content written in a text input into a link.

So if the element ID had the word Google inside it the link would end up:

```
http://www.google.com/Google
```

Any pointers / guidance would be perfect thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
onclick="window.location.href='http://www.google.com/'+document.getElementById('id').value;"
```

or

```
onclick='window.location.href="http://www.google.com/"+document.getElementById("id").value;'
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mageek/Gxb5B/13/

**Explaining step by step:**

1-`onclick=";"`
2-`onclick="window.location.href=;"`
3-`onclick="window.location.href=link+value;"`
4-`onclick="window.location.href='http://www.google.com/'+document.getElementById('id').value;"`

Without forgetting the simple quotes inside the double quotes OR the double quotes inside the simple quotes